# Is it possible to get values from a form and make a link with it?

Tags: javascript

Please help me do this if its possible.

I have a mobile community website which is powered by Wapka.mobi

There's a function on the website where members can message each other. It's a form like this;

```
<form method="get" action="messages_site.xhtml">   
<input type="text" name="username" value=" "/>   
<input type="text" name="subject" value=" "/>   
<input type="text" name="message" value=" "/>   
<input type="hidden" name="d_token" value="tokencode"/>   
</form>
```

But this form can't be edited. It displays using tags

I was wondering if i could get the hidden value from the input field and make a link where users can buzz the admin(me) without letting them type their own message. Like this;

```
<a href="message_site.xhtml?username=admin&subject=user+userid+buzzed+you&message=nothing&d_token=tokencode&submit">Send a buzz to the Admin</a>
```

But i don't know how i can get the Token code into the link. Please let me know if its possible with Javascript. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="buzzerform" method="get" action="messages_site.xhtml">   
    <input type="text" name="username" value=" "/>   
    <input type="text" name="subject" value=" "/>   
    <input type="text" name="message" value=" "/>   
    <input type="hidden" name="d_token" value="tokencode"/>   
</form>

<a id="buzzer" href="#">Send a buzz to the Admin</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('buzzer').addEventListener("click", function() {
        var newUrl = 'message_site.xhtml?username=' + document.buzzerform.username.value + ...;
        document.location.search = newUrl;
    });
</script>
```